# How to parse an input in Bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I am new to Bash and have an input file.log with the following contents:

```
ok: [test_performance=10.50.100.82] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "DeviceName:78BAY08V2A/10",
            "DeviceName:GH7AK1A02097/10"
]]}
ok: [test_1=10.50.101.84] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "DeviceName:8K251FDD4000D1/13",
            "DeviceName:99071JEGR10369/12"
]]}
```

I want to get output as below:

```
test_performance,10.50.100.82,78BAY08V2A/10
test_performance,10.50.100.82,GH7AK1A02097/10
test_1,10.50.101.84,8K251FDD4000D1/13
test_1,10.50.101.84,99071JEGR10369/12
```

I tried below command but it is not working. What can I try next?

```bash
grep -C 3 "DeviceName:" file.log | xargs | sed 's/ok/\n/g' | sed 's|[]{}[]||g' | sed 's/msg//g' | sed 's/ =>/,/g' | awk -F ":" '{print $4,$5}' | awk -F "--" '{print $1}' | sed 's/,    /,/g' | sed 's/, /-/g' | sed 's/ //g' | grep -E 'arda|kobra|pipeline|performance|integration|feature|kare|yjr' | sed 's/=/,/g' | sed 's/\(.*\)-/\1,/' | sed 's/-/,/g' | tee -a file2.csv
```

Comment: It's a bastardized json format so I suggest you extract the first two fields and pass those to jq as `-arg` and everything after => to it's stdin.  This will give you better a better parse and error handling than awk.

Comment: Fix producer to generate straight json output then use jq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk use `"`, `:`, `=`, `]` and `[` as field separators:

```
awk -F '[":=\\]\\[]' '/^ok/{ok=$3 "," $4} /DeviceName/{print ok "," $3}' file.log
```

Output:

```
test_performance,10.50.100.82,78BAY08V2A/10
test_performance,10.50.100.82,GH7AK1A02097/10
test_1,10.50.101.84,8K251FDD4000D1/13
test_1,10.50.101.84,99071JEGR10369/12
```

Comment: `POSIX` specs already mandate those be allowable inside `FS` - there's nothing particularly `gnu` specific about it. It can also be written a bit cleaner with just ::::::::::::: `-F '[][":=]'`

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code, written and tested in GNU `awk`. This will pick up lines from `ok:`  to till `}` and process them as per requirement.

```
awk -v RS='(^|\n)ok: \\[[^}]*' '
RT{
  match(RT,/ok: \[([^=]*)=([^]]*)\]/,arr)
  val=arr[1]","arr[2]
  while(match(RT,/"DeviceName:([^"]*)"/,arr)){
    print val","arr[1]
    RT=substr(RT,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

The input looks like a list of JSON objects prefixed with labels like `ok: [test_performance=10.50.100.82] =>`. So the task of parsing can be divided into two parts:

1. Parsing the prefixes.
2. Parsing the JSON objects.

The first part doesn't look like a well-known format, so I'd parse it using awk, perl, or sed. For the JSON part, there is a popular `jq` tool.

Here is one of the possible solutions using `sed` and `jq`:

```bash
sed -e 's/\(^ok: .* => \){/"\1":{/;
    1{s/^/{/};
    ${s/$/}/};
    2~1{s/"ok:/,"ok:/}
' file.log | jq --raw-output -e '.|to_entries|.[]|. as $p|.[]
    |$p.value.msg|.[]|.[]
    |sub("^DeviceName:";"") as $d
    |$p.key|capture("ok: \\[(?<test>.*)=(?<ip>.*)\\]")
    |.test+","+.ip+","+$d'
```

Where the `sed` command makes a JSON object out of the whole input. It

- Adds curly braces before the first line(`1{s/^/{/}`) and after the last line(`${s/$/}/}`).
- Surrounds the "ok:..." prefixes with double quotes.

Then the resulting JSON object is piped to the `jq` command. For the rest, I suggest the reader refer to the documentation:

- `man sed`
- `man jq`.

---

#### Choosing the right tool

While it is technically possible to parse JSON with awk, sed, or even bash, we should avoid doing so because these are general-purpose tools. Implementing a correct parser requires a program that adheres to the entire JSON specification.

Similarly, generating CSV data actually requires software specifically written for this purpose. Therefore, personally, I wouldn't use the command above in a production environment. A proper solution involves using a programming language that is more powerful than bash, awk, or sed. Using a Perl, PHP, or Node.js script would be suitable as long as the appropriate libraries are utilized.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sed script process script somewhat similar to the accepted awk answer.  Note `env -S` is a GNU coreutils extension of `env`.

If the line starts with `ok:` copy the line to the hold buffer (`h`).

If the line contains `DeviceName:` append the hold buffer to the pattern buffer (`G`).  Extract and format and order the 3 fields  of the now two lines in the pattern buffer and print (`s/.../p`) the result.

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S sed -E -n -f

/^ok:/ h
/DeviceName:/ {
    G
    s/.*:([^"]*).*\n.*\[([^=]*)=([^]]*).*/\2,\3,\1/p
}
```

and run it like this:

```
$ ./process file.log
test_performance,10.50.100.82,78BAY08V2A/10
test_performance,10.50.100.82,GH7AK1A02097/10
test_1,10.50.101.84,8K251FDD4000D1/13
test_1,10.50.101.84,99071JEGR10369/12
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bash script `process` that uses the magic of `case` pattern matching:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line
do
    case "$line" in
        ok:*)
            line=${line#*[}
            line=${line%]*}
            field12=${line/=/,}
            ;;
        *DeviceName:*)
            line=${line#*:}
            field3=${line%\"*}
            echo "$field12,$field3"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

and you would run it like this:

```
$ ./process < file.log
test_performance,10.50.100.82,78BAY08V2A/10
test_performance,10.50.100.82,GH7AK1A02097/10
test_1,10.50.101.84,8K251FDD4000D1/13
test_1,10.50.101.84,99071JEGR10369/12
```